# how to open frame from another frame Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, button, frame, new-operator

I am making a program that has multiple sub-programs but when I am trying to open a new frame, it doesn't do anything.
The program that calls the frame:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Options");
    JButton notepad = new JButton("Notepad");
    JButton todo = new JButton("To-Do List");
    NoteListe noteListener = new NoteListe();
    
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));

    frame.add(notepad);
    frame.add(todo);

    notepad.addActionListener(noteListener);
    
  }
}
```

The action listener for the notepad button:

```
import java.awt.event.*;

public class NoteListe implements ActionListener{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    new MainNote();
  }
}
```

The notepad:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MainNote {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Text Editor");

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
  }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have a misunderstanding of what a constructor is and what a method is.  Calling `new MainNote()` will do nothing, as you've not overridden `MainNote` default constructor

Comment: How would I achieve this?

Comment: To be respectful, you should already know these concepts before delving into the additional complexities of a GUI framework. You should start by reading through [Providing Constructors for Your Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html), [Defining Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html), [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Comment: It also wouldn't hurt to have an idea of [encapsulation](https://www.edureka.co/blog/encapsulation-in-java/)

Answer (score 2):

I really think you need to take a closer look at:

- [Providing Constructors for Your Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)
- [Defining Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)
- [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

These are really fundamental concepts and you should have firm grasp of them before you venture into the wild and unforgiving world of GUI development.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new MenuPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MenuPane extends JPanel {

        public MenuPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(32, 32, 32, 32));

            JButton notepad = new JButton("Notepad");
            JButton todo = new JButton("To-Do List");

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(8, 8, 8, 8);

            add(notepad, gbc);
            add(todo, gbc);

            notepad.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    MainNote note = MainNote.show(MenuPane.this);
                    note.setText("This is where your text goes");
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public static class MainNote extends JPanel {

        private JTextArea ta;

        public MainNote() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            ta = new JTextArea(20, 40);
            add(new JScrollPane(ta));
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            ta.setText(text);
        }

        public String getText() {
            return ta.getText();
        }

        public static MainNote show(Component parent) {
            MainNote mainNote = new MainNote();
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Text Editor");
            frame.add(mainNote);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            return mainNote;
        }
    }
}
```

*Note:* I've used a `static` method (`show`) to simplify the construction of another window.  This is simply a delegation workflow, as I'm delegating the responsibility for creating the window to the method, but I'm still getting back an instance of the `MainNote`.

Because `MainNote` is simply a `JPanel`, it can be added to what ever container I want.  Because I've "encapsulated" the functionality into the class itself, it makes it much easier to manage.